# Initializing members of derived class (C++)

Tags: c++, constructor, derived-class, initializing

What is the preferred method for initializing a derived class that was casted from it's base class?

Consider the following scenario:

```
    class A{
        public:
           A();
           ~A();
    }

    class B : public A{
        public:
           B() {m_b = 0.0;};
           ~B();
           float GetValue(){return m_b;};

        private: 
           float m_b;
    }


    A* a = new A;
    B* b = static_cast<B*>(a);

    float val = b->GetValue();   // This was never initialized because it was not constructed
```

My current solution is to manually call an Initialize() function which would perform the necessary initializations as the constructor would.

It seems sloppy though and there must be a better/cleaner method.

Any help and guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Matt, that `GetValue()` function should be `const`, since it doesn't alter the state of the objects it's invoked on: `float GetValue() const {return m_b;};`. What are you learning C++ from? Have a look at [this FAQ entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/). If you can learn from one of those books.

Comment: And one more thing: Casting to a derived class from a base class pointer/reference is frowned upon, and for good reasons. Why do you think you need that anyway? Your class names and minimalistic implementations (no critique, it's a great repro!) give no hints as to why you designed it that way, but I'd question such a design. Have you programmed in any OO language before?

Answer (score 5):

This is a faulty construct:

```
A* a = new A;
B* b = static_cast<B*>(a);
```

**EDIT**

It should really be:

```
B* b = new B();
```

Since, as sbi pointed out, A does not have a virtual function called GetValue(), so it can never be invoked from A.

Do not do a static_cast from A* to B*.

Comment: Actually you need to cast `a` to a `B *` since `GetValue` is `B` specific. [now why one would design the classes like this is another story]

Comment: The problem is not in the casting as this answer would have you believe. Joe Gauterin identified the proper problem in that B was not being instantiated and that a copy constructor B(A) was required.

Comment: @Matt that is no different to what I said. read what my answer says, I"m creating a B right there!!  No Copy ctor is needed here, since your class contains no pointer members

Comment: @Matt : The problem **is** in the casting, since the casting you've shown invokes [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @Tony: This is wrong. You cannot invoke `B::GetValue()` through an `A*`, since it's not declared `virtual` in the base class. In fact, it's not in the base class at all, so `a->GetValue()` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

You are casting a parent object into an object of a derived type. That is plain wrong. An object of class A does not have an m_b member to initialise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is valid at all, because the object was created with `sizeof(A)` and `sizeof(B)` is clearly larger.

Answer (score 0):

The code you described is dangerous and not valid, since B is A, but not the other way around. This would be valid:

```
B* b = new B;
A* a = dynamic_cast<A*>(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an instance of the derived class to initialize - you only have an instance of the base class. All the 1static_cast1 is doing is forcing the compiler to allow you to treat the base class as a derived class.

Instead, to create a `B`, you should be doing is this:

```
A* a = new B;
```

That will call the constructor of `B`, initializing `m_b` to `0.0`.

Comment: I realize that this is probably at the core of my problem.  I should probably be instantiating a new B that calls the base class constructor

Answer (score 0):

```
B* b = static_cast<B*>(a);
```

You should be using `static_cast` this only if you know that `a` actually points to an object of `B` or a class derived from `B`, which is clearly not the case.

It is an incorrect statement.
The valid sequence should be:

```
 A* a = new B();
 B* b = static_cast<B*>(a);
```

`a` now points to a object of the type `B`. It can do so because ***Pointer to the object of Base class can always point to the objects of the derived class, as long as it is a public derivation.***

Now, you can use `static_cast` because you know for sure that `a` actually points to object of `class B`.
There can be scenarios where in one is not aware of the hierarchy of classes and in such scenarios one cannot use `static_cast` C++ provides another cast type called `Dynamic_cast` in such scenarios, it will return a null pointer if the cast is not valid in case of pointers or throw an exception in case of references.

Point to note though `Dynamic_Cast` works only with polymorphic classes.